# Частица «не» с предикативом «повадно»

Tags: орфография, частица-не, наречия, предикатив

*Накажите его, чтобы ему **не/повадно** было воровать!*

Можно ли написать данное наречие раздельно и слитно? В одном случае отрицая признак, а в другом утверждая его (по правилам)?

Comment: Интрига еще какая, если не понимать решение ФОРМАЛЬНО.  Слитный вариант преобладает, но когда его нужно использовать? Да и существует ли вообще раздельно письмо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны варианты:

(1) *Накажите его, чтобы ему **неповадно** было воровать!*  Утверждение.

(2)  *Накажите его, чтобы ему **не повАдно** было воровать!* Отрицание.

Более частотным будет **слитное** написание. Отрицание возможно при логическом подчеркивании.

Также при инверсии: *Накажите его, чтобы **не повАдно** ему  было воровать!*

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81)**

5. Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей не слитно при утверждении: нетрудно видеть и раздельно при отрицании: не трудно видеть (смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим).

**НЕПОВАДНО,** в функц. сказ. Устар. Непривычно, не по себе. * В поле одной-то надсадно, В поле одной неповадно (Некрасов). ◊ **Чтобы неповадно было.** Чтобы впредь не вошло в привычку. Наказать так, чтобы неповадно было

Answer (score 1):

Не повадно - это уже не предикат, а глагол.

Чтобы *не* писалось раздельно нужен другой предикат, который перетянет условность на себя:

*Накажите его, чтоб **и другим** не повадно было воровать!*

*Накажите его, чтобы ему не повадно было **боле** воровать!*

Но без предиката, а ему на предикацию никак не тянет, я не вижу оснований писать раздельно:

*Накажите его, чтобы ему неповадно было воровать!*

Можно, конечно, интонационно попытаться разделить не и повадно, но это уже от лукавого.

Из текстов:

> ..вкинуть на месяц в тюрьму, чтоб им **вперед** не повадно было ослушаться. Соловьев.

> ..табак у них вынут и сожжен перед ними же, чтоб им *неповадно* было вперед вино и табак на продажу привозить. Соловьев.

Вперед не повадно было ослушаться. - вперед - предикация, поэтому раздельно.

Неповадно было вперед вино привозить. - тут вперед относится к вино, вероятно.

> **Так-де** чинить не повадно! Толстой.

> ..штобы **вперед** не повадно было охальничать. Мамин-Сибиряк.

> «да чтоб **и другим** не повадно было». Соловьев.

> Только без компании не повадно-с. Островский.

Либо открепляем предикат от глагола, и он становится глаголом. Предикат - несамостоятельное наречие видимо.

*Накажите его, чтобы не воровал, чтобы не повадно!*

Либо добавляем обстоятельство:

> Они основательны и крепко прижмут немецкую агрессию, чтобы ей не повадно было мечтать **о реванше**. Волков.

*Накажите его, чтобы не повадно было воровать **в магазине**!*

То есть идея в следующем: не достаточно сказать, что, мол, отрицание или утверждение, потому что **отрицание должно быть обусловлено**, а утверждение - нет.

Можно попробовать добавить И для смещения акцента, но не уверен, что ЕМУ может быть наречием, хотя:

*Накажите его, чтоб **и ему** не повадно было воровать!*

То есть **и ему** ~ **ему, как и другим** - то есть **не ему именно**, а **ему-другому**. Появляются доп. смыслы и вроде звучит.

В остальных случаях: другим/ему/ей неповадно было - устойчивое словосочетание. И пишется слитно.

Comment: Очень интересно (голос от меня).  Формально  это все-таки предикатив/ категория состояния. Обычно возможны две формы письма. В современном языке присутствуют обе (слитная или раздельная), что видно по словарям. Я тоже считаю, что выбор отрицания нужно объяснять, если существует слово со слитным написанием.  Вы объясняете это по семантике, а я по логическому выделению или по инверсии.

Comment: Возможно, по инверсии или лог выделению можно, но да, у меня появилась идея, что отрицание, в отличие от утверждения требует объяснения, содержащее иную предикативность или какое обстоятельство. Возможно, это какой-то момент связанный вообще с логикой. То есть нельзя сказать: нет, ты не прав - это вызовет вопросы, почему не прав. А утверждать согласие можно и без объяснений. И при рассмотрении текстов на НК это заметно, там именно что в каждом случае раздельного написания есть какая-то дополнительная акцентуация или предикация.