# слова "насмерть" и "на смерть"

Tags: наречия

Как правильно написать: ***начался бой (на)смерть/на смерть.***

С одной стороны, бой (какой) насмерть.
С другой стороны, бой до смерти.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475781/Частица-не-с-предикативом-повадно вот это вроде похожее. Мне кажется, что слитное написание по умолчанию, но если есть иная предикация, то возможно раздельное. До смерти - смерти в косвенном падеже.

Comment: @Буратино Ссылка  вроде бы не та.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *Начался бой **насмерть.***

При раздельном написании **предложное управление**: идти (на что?) на смерть.

***Был бой насмерть,** лейтенант Княжко, раненный, не ушел с поля боя, самолично подбил несколько вражеских танков и погиб у орудия.*

*Остап спрятал под пиджак свой маузер и беспрепятственно выбрался из подвала, с тем чтобы снова начать борьбу **не на жизнь, а на смерть** с бандитами.*

**Орфографический словарь**

насмерть, нареч. (сражён пулей насмерть; стоять насмерть; перепугаться насмерть), но сущ. на смерть и на смерть (сознательно идёт на риск и на смерть; не на жизнь, а на смерть).

**НАСМЕРТЬ,** нареч. 1. Так, что наступает смерть; до смерти. Ранить, забить н. Задавить человека н. Н. разбиться. 2. Не щадя жизни, до решительного исхода. Н. сражаться, биться. Стоять н. где-л. (не отступать несмотря ни на что). 3. Разг.-сниж. Очень сильно. Н. перепугаться, перетрусить.