# «Идут в бой на смерть» или «Идут в бой насмерть»?

Tags: орфография, морфология, слитно-раздельно

В одном из школьных пособий увидел такое упражнение:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заинтересовала следующая пара предложений:

> *За Родину солдаты идут в бой **(на) смерть.***
>
> *Я увидела волка и **(на) смерть** перепугалась.*

В задании требуется определить, в каком из парных предложений представлено существительное с предлогом, а в каком — наречие.

То, что во втором предложении ***(на)  смерть*** — наречие, понятно: ***перепугалась*** (как?) — ***насмерть*** (слитное написание).

В первом же предложении ***(на) смерть*** является определением: ***бой*** (какой?) — ***(на) смерть*** (= смертельный).

Как следует писать ***(на) смерть*** в первом предложении предложении — слитно или раздельно? Что в этом предложении представлено — наречие или же существительное с предлогом?

**P.S.**

В интернете встречается и то, и другое написание. Я склоняюсь к раздельному, как в этом примере из книги [Лазарев Л.И. *Константин Симонов: жизнь и творчество*; М., «Русский язык», 1990]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На смерть - это умирать, а насмерть - отчаянно, вопреки смерти. Лазарева зарезал контекст, не понятно.

Comment: Из того что читается: ...возненавидел тех, для кого "идея" и "идеал" были не словами, которыми надо умело пользоваться, а тем, за что идут в бой на смерть. - тут на_смерть, посылали на смерть за идею, когда умело пользовались словами, заставляли умирать за идею. За что идут в бой умирать, по причине чего идут без возможности победить, в бессмысленный бой, умирать.

Comment: За Родину солдаты идут в бой на_смерть - не корректно. Перепугались насмерть - не умерли то есть, но очень сильно перепугались, близко к смерти.

Comment: @Буратино: «За Родину солдаты идут в бой на_смерть - не корректно». === Ну а «Начался бой на/смерть» – корректно? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475833/слова-насмерть-и-на-смерть

Comment: У меня выходит очень длинно, я не знаю, пугать вас или нет). Но если кратко, то фраза некорректна и возбуждает идеологический срач, и составил её либо человек неграмотный незнайка, либо злонамеренный.  Начался бой насмерть - верно, на смерть - не оправдано. Ну либо это какая-то заранее задуманная смертельная дуэль, бой пока один из участников не умрёт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. А я предлагаю решать задачи в соответствии **со значением падежей**, так надежнее будет. Все предложения конкретны, нужную **грамматическую модель** каждый автор выбирает **по ситуации.** Не стоит ориентироваться  на уже решенные примеры, но следует их учитывать.
2. В этой теме предлагаются **три модели**, которые мы видим в словарях.

(1) **Предметное существительное,** падежный вопрос: идти (на что?) **на смЕрть.** Сознательно идёт **на риск и на смЕрть.**

(2) **Обстоятельственное существительное** (наречное выражение), обстоятельственный вопрос **(куда?)** о направлении/ориентации, что характерно для В.п.:
Сражались **не на жизнь, а нА смерть**.

(3) **Наречие** (как?): сражён пулей **нАсмерть**; стоять **нАсмерть**; перепугаться **нАсмерть.**

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

*За Родину солдаты идут в бой **нА смерть***. Наречное выражение  в роли несогласованного определения (смертельный бой).

За что солдаты идут в бой нА смерть (смертельный бой).

Также:

*За Родину солдаты ***идут*** в бой **не на жизнь, а на смЕрть.*** Существительное.

*За Родину солдаты ***сражаются*** **не на жизнь, а нА смерть.***  Наречное выражение.

*За Родину солдаты стояли ***насмерть***.*  Наречие.

**Орфографический словарь**

**насмерть,** нареч. (сражён пулей насмерть; стоять насмерть; перепугаться насмерть), но сущ. на смЕрть и нА смерть (сознательно идёт на риск и на смЕрть; не на жизнь, а нА смерть)

**Большой толковый словарь**

**НАСМЕРТЬ**, нареч. 1. Так, что наступает смерть; до смерти. Ранить, забить н. Задавить человека н. Н. разбиться. 2. Не щадя жизни, до решительного исхода. Н. сражаться, биться. Стоять н. где-л. (не отступать несмотря ни на что). 3. Разг.-сниж. Очень сильно. Н. перепугаться, перетрусить.

Comment: Sharon, честно говоря, не понял, как статьи в _Орфографическом_ и _Большом толковом_ словарях могут подкрепить решение о необходимости именно слитного написания _**на/смерть**_  в предложенных Вами выше примерах. **Ведь во всех абсолютно примерах со слитным написанием в этих словарях**  _НАСМЕРТЬ_  входит в глагольные словосочетания с вопросом КАК? и является безусловным наречием. В Ваших же первом и втором примерах (_За Родину солдаты идут в бой **нАсмерть**_ …) вряд ли к _**на/смерть**_ можно задать такой же вопрос от глагола  _**идут**_. Более логичный: бой какой? — на/смерть.

Comment: Я исправила в примерах для сравнения: идут (на что)  и сражаются (как). В обоих случаях  использованы однородные отношения.

Comment: Есть наречия со слитным написанием НАсмерть, а есть наречные выражения с обстоятельственным значением и раздельным написанием НА смерть. Надо ориентироваться на значение глагола: идти, стоять, сражаться.

Comment: Sharon, я понимаю сочетания _**стоять нАсмерть, сражаться нАсмерть**_. Но _**идти нАсмерть**_…❓❓❓

Comment: Все исправлено. Теперь я молодец?

Comment:  Чувствую какой-то подвох… Подумаю до вечера.

Comment: Мудро, Шерон-с.

Comment: От меня плюс таки.

Comment: I am pleased with your support, sir.

Comment: В текущей редакции Ваш ответ, Sharon, совершенно логично, на мой взгляд, построен. Поддержу его. Почему другие участники форума (или надо какое-то другое слово вместо _форум_ употреблять?) оставляют его без поддержки – не понимаю!  P. S. Пока сочинял этот свой комментарий, два человека, как оказалось, успели-таки меня опередить с поддержкой Вашего ответа!

Comment: Спасибо. Редактировать действительно пришлось. Вопрос сложный, не все получалось сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, скажем, что, есть мы используем глагол, правильно талько наречное выражение, так как мы задаём наречный вопрос *как?*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3.

> Коты дворовые с собачонками биться насмерть будут, если одни у других сардельку стяпают-таки.

Как показывает практика, оба написания — и *насмерть*, и *на смерть*, — так сказать, возможны при слове *бой*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3. К сожалению, нет ещё ни одного правила чёткого по этому поводу.

> За Родину солдаты идут в бой насмерть / на смерть.

P. S. Я предлагаю использовать *на смерть*, т. к., как видно, его обычно используют грамм. книжонки.

Comment: Леопольд: «_К сожалению, нет ещё ни одного правила чёткого по этому поводу_». ===   За это плюс от меня. Я тоже не сумел найти похожих примеров ни в правилах, ни в словарях.

Comment: А орфографический словарь вам никак не помог разобраться? По-моему там все четко обозначено, все модели расписаны. Ну это по-моему)  А это другое решение: нет ничего  ясного, ничего не можем НАЙТИ, пишем как кому вздумается. Ожидаемое РЕШЕНИЕ по этой сложной теме)  И даже эмоции обозначены... Очень сожалеем!))